# What's the best way to write an if statement that won't break on an out of bounds check?

Tags: python, if-statement, indexoutofboundsexception

In a for loop, what's the best way to check a previous and next in a list without getting an index out of bounds? (See code below)

Let's say I'm writing a function to check if every color is next to another of the same color, such as:

```
def colorChecker(colorList):
    colors = True
    for i in range(len(colorList)): #No editing this line
        if not ((i > 0 and colorList[i] == colorList[i-1]) or ((i < len(colorList)-1) and colorList[i] == colorList[i+1])):
            colors = False
    return colors
```

This gives me an index out of bounds exception...

I'm attempting to check for the index out of bounds and bounce it from the if statement before it goes into checking `colorList[len(colorlist)+1]`...but obviously this isn't the correct way to do it. How would you better write this?

Answer (score 3):

It is better to iterate over three set of elements like this, using `zip`

```
for prev,cur,nxt in zip(colorList, colorList[1:], colorList[2:]):
    if (prev == cur) or (cur == nxt):
         # Do something
```

Comment: This doesn't handle both comparing with the previous value and comparing with the next value

Comment: Unfortunately the fix does not answer the question either. This only checks that both previous and next values match whereas the question only asks for either to match

Comment: sorry for being pedantic. Good answer

Comment: @Sunitha if I have to keep the for loop as is, is there any workaround? In the actual code I'm writing I'm iterating through the whole for loop and need it to stay the same.

Comment: If you really don't want to implement any of the suggestions, change the last condition `colorList[i] == colorList[i+1]` to `colorList[i] == min(colorList[i+1], len(colorList) - 1)`

Comment: I would like to point out that, even though this answer does not fit your particular use case, it's the best answer to the question as formulated in the title (thus relevant for people who end up here from google). The best way to avoid the 'out of bounds' error is not to bother with indices to begin with :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're checking previous and next elements, you only need to start from the second element and end at the next to last element (you can also break after `colors = False`, since one invalid triple is enough):

```
for i in range(1, len(colorList) - 1):
    if not(colorList[i] == colorList[i-1] or colorList[i] == colorList[i+1]):
        # ... etc
```

If you need to check the first and last elements as well, use this:

```
for i in range(len(colorList)):
    if not((i > 0 and colorList[i] == colorList[i-1]) or (i < len(colorList) - 1 and colorList[i] == colorList[i+1])):
        colors = False
        break
```

Comment: In the actual function I'm working with I actually have to reference the beginning and the end as well- this was just a simplified version of the question - so I have to keep the "for i in range(len(colorlist))" without changes

Comment: @Jim but adding tests for the first and last items will ignore them anyway. Anyway, if you have (probably) more code in the loop, then check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! So in this case, if i == len(colorList)-1, that part of the statement is processed first and it never goes onto the colorlist[i+1] check part of the if statement, correct? That was the part I wasn't sure about - and wasn't sure if I was getting the error there.

Comment: @Jim Yes, because it's a logical `AND` statement, if the first condition is `False`, there is no need to check the other conditions because no matter what, the overall result of the `AND` statement will be `False` (same thing with the first statement `i > 0`).

Answer (score 1):

@MrGeek is entirely correct, and @Sunitha's technique is even more elegant -- I suggest you use one of their solutions since they avoid unnecessary logic.

But the answer to *why* are you getting 'index out of bounds' is because your second check is `i < len(colorList)` when it should be `i < len(colorList) - 1`.

Arrays being 0-indexed, the valid indice range for an array of size **n** is **[0 ... n-1]**.

---

*EDIT:* Taking a step back, those errors happen because your if-condition is a bit complicated. I would advise breaking it down to smaller pieces -- keeping your loop unchanged, I would write:

```
def colorChecker(colorList):
    colors = True
    for i in range(len(colorList)):
        prevI = i - 1;
        nextI = i + 1;
        isDifferentFromPrev = prevI < 0 or colorList[i] != colorList[prevI]
        isDifferentFromNext = nextI >= len(colorList) or colorList[i] != colorList[nextI]

        if isDifferentFromPrev and isDifferentFromNext:
            colors = False

    return colors
```

Note I made a few ["not (a or b)" to "not a and not b"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) substitutions to simplify.

Reading the above code, you immediately understand what is being done: *setting `colors` to `False` if any color in the array is different from the colors surrounding it*.

Comment: Yes, good point, good catch and edited! (Question still stands as I believe the out of bounds error still exists)

Comment: Do you *believe* it still exists, or can you *confirm* it does?